Hugging face; Problem with custom retriever in transformers library
I am trying to build a RAG-based Chatbot with Chain of Thought for WordPress Site. I am not very experienced with Hugging face. I am using API to retrieve the data for this.
Problem description:
I have built a custom retriever for the rag model. I know that I can use RagRetriever, I tried and I am having severe problems with version control as it requires me to import datasets.
After running the program, the Error says that, my 'CustomRetriever' object is not callable. Is there a way around this?
I'm using,
Python v3.10.12
Transformers v4.42.0 dev0
My Custom Retriever Class
# Custom Retriever Class
class CustomRetriever:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index

    def retrieve(self, query_embedding, n_docs=5):
        distances, indices = self.index.search(query_embedding, n_docs)
        return indices

# Initialize RAG components
tokenizer = RagTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/rag-sequence-nq")
rag_model = RagSequenceForGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/rag-sequence-nq")

# Initialize Custom Retriever
custom_retriever = CustomRetriever(index=index)

# Set the retriever for RAG model
rag_model.set_retriever(custom_retriever)

My implementation(passing input ids and attention mask)
# Maintain a conversation history
conversation_history = []

def process_query_with_chain_of_thought(user_query, previous_context=""):
    # Tokenize the input query
    inputs = tokenizer(user_query, return_tensors="pt")

    # Generate embeddings for the query
    query_embedding = model.encode([user_query]).reshape(1, -1)

    # Retrieve relevant document indices
    doc_indices = custom_retriever.retrieve(query_embedding, n_docs=5)

    # Debugging: Print retrieved document indices
    # print(f"Retrieved document indices: {doc_indices}")

    # Fetch actual documents
    retrieved_docs = []
    for i in doc_indices[0]:
        if 0 <= i < len(posts):
            retrieved_docs.append(posts[i]['content']['rendered'])
        else:
            print(f"Index {i} is out of range.")

    # Print the retrieved documents in a human-readable format
    # print("Retrieved documents:")
    full_content = ""
    for doc in retrieved_docs:
        # Clean HTML and convert to plain text
        cleaned_text = clean_html(doc)
        # print(cleaned_text)  # Print the extracted text
        # print("="*50)   # Separate each document with a line of '='
        full_content += cleaned_text + "\n\n"

    # Combine user query and retrieved documents to create context
    context = user_query + "\n\n" + full_content

    if context:
        # Tokenize the retrieved documents
        context_inputs = tokenizer(full_content, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512)

        # Ensure that context_input_ids are passed correctly
        response_ids = rag_model.generate(
            input_ids=inputs['input_ids'],
            context_input_ids=context_inputs['input_ids'],
            context_attention_mask=context_inputs['attention_mask']
        )

        response_text = tokenizer.decode(response_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

        # Append the initial response to the conversation history
        conversation_history.append(f"User: {user_query}")
        conversation_history.append(f"Bot: {response_text}")

        # Create a new context by combining the conversation history
        new_context = "\n".join(conversation_history)

        # # Debug: print the final response
        # print("Final response:")
        # print(new_context)

        return response_text, new_context
    else:
        print("No documents retrieved")
        return "Sorry, I couldn't find any relevant information.", previous_context

Queries:
# Example multi-turn conversation
user_queries = [
    "Are there any news on fiction stories?",
    "Which one is the most populer",
    "What are the reviews."
]


context = ""
for query in user_queries:
    response, context = process_query_with_chain_of_thought(query, previous_context=context)
    print(f"Processed response: {response}\n")

Error message:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-c7d6867da07f> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 context = ""
      2 for query in user_queries:
----> 3     response, context = process_query_with_chain_of_thought(query, previous_context=context)
      4     print(f"Processed response: {response}\n")

8 frames

<ipython-input-20-3284408ddf21> in process_query_with_chain_of_thought(user_query, previous_context)
     41 
     42         # Ensure that context_input_ids are passed correctly
---> 43         response_ids = rag_model.generate(
     44             input_ids=inputs['input_ids'],
     45             context_input_ids=context_inputs['input_ids'],

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
    113     def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
    114         with ctx_factory():
--> 115             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    116 
    117     return decorate_context

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/rag/modeling_rag.py in generate(self, input_ids, attention_mask, context_input_ids, context_attention_mask, doc_scores, do_deduplication, num_return_sequences, num_beams, n_docs, **model_kwargs)
   1019             if input_ids is not None:
   1020                 new_input_ids = input_ids[index : index + 1].repeat(num_candidates, 1)
-> 1021                 outputs = self(new_input_ids, labels=output_sequences, exclude_bos_score=True)
   1022             else:  # input_ids is None, need context_input_ids/mask and doc_scores
   1023                 assert context_attention_mask is not None, (

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1530             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1531         else:
-> 1532             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1533 
   1534     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1539                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1540                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1541             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1542 
   1543         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/rag/modeling_rag.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, encoder_outputs, decoder_input_ids, decoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, context_input_ids, context_attention_mask, doc_scores, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, output_retrieved, exclude_bos_score, reduce_loss, labels, n_docs, **kwargs)
    843             use_cache = False
    844 
--> 845         outputs = self.rag(
    846             input_ids=input_ids,
    847             attention_mask=attention_mask,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1530             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1531         else:
-> 1532             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1533 
   1534     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1539                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1540                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1541             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1542 
   1543         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/rag/modeling_rag.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, encoder_outputs, decoder_input_ids, decoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, doc_scores, context_input_ids, context_attention_mask, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, output_retrieved, n_docs)
    591                 question_encoder_last_hidden_state = question_enc_outputs[0]  # hidden states of question encoder
    592 
--> 593                 retriever_outputs = self.retriever(
    594                     input_ids,
    595                     question_encoder_last_hidden_state.cpu().detach().to(torch.float32).numpy(),

TypeError: 'CustomRetriever' object is not callable

If you want any more details, please do let me know. Thanks.
